# php pagination with search not working together?

Tags: php, mysql, row

This is the small minor project from college. It ranks the students as per the no of votes. It does rank the student in the pagination but when the student profile is clicked the rank is not shown.
Ok so the below code works but the last part of the code does not display the rank in the output. how can I $num in both codes?

```
<a href="/">HOME</a>
<br><br>

<form>
<input type="text" name="id" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter student id">
</form>

<br><br>

<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result_per_page = 5;
$no_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$no_of_page = ceil($no_of_result/$result_per_page);


if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
   $page = 1;
}else{
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}

$page_first = ($page-1)*$result_per_page;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT ' . $page_first . ',' . $result_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$num = $page * $result_per_page -4;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<div class="x">';
  echo '#';
  echo $num++;
   echo ' ';
   echo '<a href="?id='.$row['id'].'">';
   echo $row['name'];
   echo '</a>';
   echo '</div>';
}

echo '<br>';

    for($page=1;$page<=$no_of_page;$page++){
   echo '<a href="/?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>';
   echo ' ';
    }


echo '<br>';
?>



<?php
$name = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo '<br>';
      echo 'RANK = ';
      echo '?';//display rank here?
      echo '<br>';
      echo 'NAME = ';
      echo $row['name'];
      echo '<br>';
      echo 'VOTES = ';
      echo $row['votes'];
      echo '<br>';
    }
} else {
    //echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

The output of the above code.. I want to output the rank in the place of question mark.
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hheuz.png)

i want something like this
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xvpk.png)

Comment: The images look the same (aside from 1 being a larger cropping area). What do you want? Instead of `select *` do `select count(*)` select the count and use that.

Comment: i want RANK to display. check the question mark in the first img